# Issue with Game of Life

Tags: java, swing, conways-game-of-life

I'm working on a Java implementation of Conway's game of life as a personal project for myself. So far it works but the rules are coming out wrong. The expected patterns aren't showing up as well as it should. Is there something wrong with my code?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Cell extends JComponent implements MouseListener {

  private int row, col;
  private boolean isLiving;

  public Cell(int r, int c) {
    this.row = r;
    this.col = c;
    this.addMouseListener(this);
  }

  public void isAlive(int neighbors) {
    if (this.isLiving) {
      if (neighbors < 2) {
        this.isLiving = false;
      } else if (neighbors == 2 || neighbors == 3) {
        this.isLiving = true;
      } else if (neighbors > 3) {
        this.isLiving = false;
      }
    } else {
      if (neighbors == 3) {
        this.isLiving = true;
      }
    }
  }

  public boolean isLiving() {
    return this.isLiving;
  }

  public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    if (this.isLiving) {
      g.fillRect(0, 0, 10, 10);
    } else {
      g.drawRect(0, 0, 10, 10);
    }
  }

  public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    this.isLiving = !this.isLiving;
  }

  public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
  }

  public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
  }

  public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
  }

  public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean, "the rules are coming out wrong"?

Comment: Code Review is strictly for working code. Feel free to bring your code back to code review once it is working for stylistic/performance suggestions.

Comment: It'd be easier if you said *how* they were coming out wrong, and included the code you used to calculate a cell's neighbors. Also need to know if you're wrapping around or in an endless world.

Comment: `"Issue with Game of Life"` Maybe if you didn't view life as a game ...?

Comment: Please provide an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits the problem you describe.

Comment: For instance, the blinker and toad patterns don't ever stabilize. The only ones that seem to work are the still patterns. Does anyone know if i've implemented them correctly?

Comment: *"Does anyone know if i've implemented them correctly?"*  Apparently not, but only an SSCCE will tell for sure.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I *suspect*<sup>1</sup> the problem with your code is that it is setting the cells to living or dead as soon as the neighbors are checked.  That caused my early variants of this code to fail.  That change of state has to be delayed until the entire grid (biosphere) has been checked.

This example shows typical Game of Life behavior.

1. Note that "suspicions ain't answers", so it is best to post an SSCCE.

[image: Game of Life]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class GameOfLife extends JPanel {

    private final int row, col;
    private boolean isLiving;

    public static Random random = new Random();

    public GameOfLife(int r, int c) {
        this.row = r;
        this.col = c;
        MouseListener listener = new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                isLiving = !isLiving;
                repaint();
            }
        };
        this.addMouseListener(listener);
        isLiving = random.nextBoolean();
    }

    public boolean isAlive(int neighbors) {
        boolean alive = false;
        if (this.isLiving) {
            if (neighbors < 2) {
                alive = false;
            } else if (neighbors == 2 || neighbors == 3) {
                alive = true;
            } else if (neighbors > 3) {
                alive = false;
            }
        } else {
            if (neighbors == 3) {
                alive = true;
            }
        }
        return alive;
    }

    public void setAlive(boolean alive) {
        isLiving = alive;
    }

    public boolean isLiving() {
        return this.isLiving;
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if (this.isLiving) {
            g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth() - 1, getHeight() - 1);
        } else {
            g.drawRect(0, 0, getWidth() - 1, getHeight() - 1);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int s = 40;
        final GameOfLife[][] biosphere = new GameOfLife[s][s];
        final JPanel gui = new JPanel(new GridLayout(s, s, 2, 2));
        for (int ii = 0; ii < s; ii++) {
            for (int jj = 0; jj < s; jj++) {
                GameOfLife cell = new GameOfLife(ii, jj);
                cell.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(10, 10));
                gui.add(cell);
                biosphere[ii][jj] = cell;
            }
        }

        ActionListener al = (ActionEvent ae) -> {
            boolean[][] living = new boolean[s][s];
            for (int ii = 0; ii < s; ii++) {
                for (int jj = 0; jj < s; jj++) {
                    int top = (jj > 0 ? jj - 1 : s - 1);
                    int btm = (jj < s - 1 ? jj + 1 : 0);
                    int lft = (ii > 0 ? ii - 1 : s - 1);
                    int rgt = (ii < s - 1 ? ii + 1 : 0);
                    int neighbors = 0;
                    if (biosphere[ii][top].isLiving()) {
                        neighbors++;
                    }
                    if (biosphere[ii][btm].isLiving()) {
                        neighbors++;
                    }
                    if (biosphere[lft][top].isLiving()) {
                        neighbors++;
                    }
                    if (biosphere[lft][btm].isLiving()) {
                        neighbors++;
                    }
                    if (biosphere[lft][jj].isLiving()) {
                        neighbors++;
                    }
                    if (biosphere[rgt][jj].isLiving()) {
                        neighbors++;
                    }
                    if (biosphere[rgt][top].isLiving()) {
                        neighbors++;
                    }
                    if (biosphere[rgt][btm].isLiving()) {
                        neighbors++;
                    }
                    living[ii][jj] = biosphere[ii][jj].isAlive(neighbors);
                }
            }
            for (int ii = 0; ii < s; ii++) {
                for (int jj = 0; jj < s; jj++) {
                    biosphere[ii][jj].setAlive(living[ii][jj]);
                }
            }
            gui.repaint();
        };

        Timer timer = new Timer(50, al);
        timer.start();

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, gui);
        timer.stop();
    }
}
```