# The game of life(Conway's game) - how to check for cell neighbours

Tags: java

Hello everyone I am trying to count the number of neighbours cell, diagonal included in my 2 dimensional array. After that I will run the program which using the rule of The game of life, will fill my new grid. However I am stuck with an indexOutOfBoundsException and I cannot figure out where I am doing wrong, I hope someone can help me, here the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

class LifeGrid
{
    private int[][] grid;
    private int generation;

    public LifeGrid(int x, int y, String filename) throws FileNotFoundException 
    { 
        grid = new int[x][y];
        int j = 0;

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(filename));

        while(scanner.hasNextLine() && j < x)
        {
            String line = scanner.nextLine();
            for(int i=0; i<line.length() && i<y; i++)
            {
                if(line.charAt(i) == '*')
                    grid[j][i] = 1;
                else
                    grid[j][i] = 0;
            }
            j++;
        }
        scanner.close();
    }

    public void show()
    {
        for(int i=0; i<grid.length; i++)
        {
            for(int j=0; j<grid[i].length; j++)
            {
                if(grid[i][j] == 1)
                    System.out.print("*");
                else
                    System.out.print(" "); 
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println("Generation:" + generation);
    }

    //Getter methods

    public int getWidth()             { return grid[0].length;  }
    public int getHeight()            { return grid.length;     }
    public int getGeneration()        { return this.generation; }
    public int getCell(int x, int y)  { return grid[x][y];      }


    public static void main(String[] args)throws FileNotFoundException 
    {
        LifeGrid life = new LifeGrid(6, 10, args[0]);
        life.run(); 
    }

    //Check neighbours

    public int neighbours(int x, int y)
    {
        int neighbours = 0;

        if(x >= 1 && y >= 1 && x < getHeight() && y < getWidth())
        {
            if(grid[x][y++] == 1)       {neighbours++;} 
            if(grid[x][y--] == 1)       {neighbours++;}
            if(grid[x++][y] == 1)       {neighbours++;}
            if(grid[x++][y++] == 1)     {neighbours++;} 
            if(grid[x++][y--] == 1)     {neighbours++;}
            if(grid[x--][y--] == 1)     {neighbours++;}
            if(grid[x--][y++] == 1)     {neighbours++;}
        }
        else if(x == 0 && y == 0)
        {
            if(grid[x][y++] == 1)       {neighbours++;} 
            if(grid[x++][y] == 1)       {neighbours++;}
            if(grid[x++][y++] == 1)     {neighbours++;}
        }
        else if(x == 0 && y >= 1 && y < getWidth() && x < getHeight())
        {
            if(grid[x][y++] == 1)       {neighbours++;} 
            if(grid[x][y--] == 1)       {neighbours++;}
            if(grid[x++][y] == 1)       {neighbours++;}
            if(grid[x++][y++] == 1)     {neighbours++;} 
            if(grid[x++][y--] == 1)     {neighbours++;}
        }
        else if(x >= 1 && x < getHeight() && y == 0 && y < getWidth())
        {
            if(grid[x][y++] == 1)       {neighbours++;} 
            if(grid[x++][y] == 1)       {neighbours++;}
            if(grid[x++][y++] == 1)     {neighbours++;} 
            if(grid[x--][y++] == 1)     {neighbours++;}
        }
        else if(x == getHeight() && y >= 1 && y < getWidth())
        {
            if(grid[x][y++] == 1)       {neighbours++;} 
            if(grid[x][y--] == 1)       {neighbours++;}
            if(grid[x--][y--] == 1)     {neighbours++;}
            if(grid[x--][y++] == 1)     {neighbours++;}
        }
        else if(x >=1 && x < getHeight() && y == getWidth())
        {
            if(grid[x][y--] == 1)       {neighbours++;}
            if(grid[x++][y] == 1)       {neighbours++;}
            if(grid[x++][y--] == 1)     {neighbours++;}
            if(grid[x--][y--] == 1)     {neighbours++;}
        }
        else if(x == 0 && y == getWidth())
        {   
            if(grid[x][y--] == 1)       {neighbours++;}
            if(grid[x++][y] == 1)       {neighbours++;}
            if(grid[x++][y--] == 1)     {neighbours++;}
        }
        else if(x == getHeight() && y == 0)
        {
            if(grid[x--][y] == 1)       {neighbours++;}
            if(grid[x][++y] == 1)       {neighbours++;}
            if(grid[x--][y++] == 1)     {neighbours++;}
        }
        else if(x == getHeight() && y == getWidth())
        {
            if(grid[x][y--] == 1)       {neighbours++;}
            if(grid[x--][y] == 1)       {neighbours++;}
            if(grid[x--][y--] == 1)     {neighbours++;}
        }
        return neighbours;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        int[][] newGrid = grid;
        int[][] swapGrid = grid;;
        for(int i=0; i<grid.length; i++)
        {
            for(int j=0; j<grid[i].length; j++)
            {
                if(grid[i][j] == 1)
                {
                    if(neighbours(i,j) < 2)     generation = 0;
                    if(neighbours(i,j) > 3)     generation = 0;
                    if(neighbours(i,j) == 2)    generation = 1;
                }
                if(neighbours(i,j) == 3)        generation = 1;
                if(generation == 1)
                {
                    swapGrid[i][j] = 1;
                    newGrid = swapGrid;     
                }
                else
                {
                    swapGrid[i][j] = 0;
                    newGrid = swapGrid;
                }
            }
        }
        grid = newGrid;
        show();
    }
}
```

Exception details:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10 at   
LifeGrid.neighbours(LifeGrid.java:87) at LifeGrid.run(LifeGrid.java:150) at 
LifeGrid.main(LifeGrid.java:59)
```

---

Thank you guys for your immediate answers, now the code works and I can see my output. However I have noticed that my algorithm in the run() method is completely wrong because I am getting different outputs from the rules of the Game of Life.
Rules:

For a space that is 'populated':

Each cell with one or no neighbors dies, as if by loneliness.
Each cell with four or more neighbors dies, as if by overpopulation.
Each cell with two or three neighbors survives.
For a space that is 'empty' or 'unpopulated':

Each cell with three neighbors becomes populated.

The file which the program uses is designed like:

```
                                          * * *
```

Therefore following the rules I should have as output:

```
                                          *
                                          *
                                          *
```

Here my code:

```
  import java.util.Scanner;
  import java.io.*;

  class LifeGrid
  {
    private int[][] grid;
    private int generation;

    public LifeGrid(int x, int y, String filename) throws FileNotFoundException 
    {  
        grid = new int[x][y];
        int j = 0;

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(filename));

        while(scanner.hasNextLine() && j < x)
        {
                String line = scanner.nextLine();

            for(int i=0; i<line.length() && i<y; i++)
            {
                if(line.charAt(i) == '*')
                    grid[j][i] = 1;
                else
                    grid[j][i] = 0;
            }
            j++;
        }
        scanner.close();
    }

    public void show()
    {
        for(int i=0; i<grid.length; i++)
        {
            for(int j=0; j<grid[i].length; j++)
            {
                if(grid[i][j] == 1)
                    System.out.print("*");
                else
                    System.out.print(" "); 
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println("Generation:" + generation);
    }

//Getter methods

    public int getWidth()             { return grid[0].length;  }
    public int getHeight()            { return grid.length;     }
    public int getGeneration()        { return this.generation; }
    public int getCell(int x, int y)  { return grid[x][y];      }


    public static void main(String[] args)throws FileNotFoundException 
    {
        LifeGrid life = new LifeGrid(6, 10, args[0]);
        life.run(); 
        }

//Check neighbours

    public int neighbours(int x, int y)
    {
        int neighbours = 0;

        if(x >= 1 && y >= 1 && x < getHeight() -1 && y < getWidth() -1)
        {
            if(grid[x][y+1] == 1)       {neighbours++;} 
            if(grid[x][y-1] == 1)       {neighbours++;}
            if(grid[x+1][y] == 1)       {neighbours++;}
            if(grid[x+1][y+1] == 1)     {neighbours++;} 
            if(grid[x+1][y-1] == 1)     {neighbours++;}
            if(grid[x-1][y-1] == 1)     {neighbours++;}
            if(grid[x-1][y+1] == 1)     {neighbours++;}
        }
        else if(x == 0 && y == 0)
        {
            if(grid[x][y+1] == 1)       {neighbours++;} 
            if(grid[x+1][y] == 1)       {neighbours++;}
            if(grid[x+1][y+1] == 1)     {neighbours++;}
        }
        else if(x == 0 && y >= 1 && y < getWidth() -1 && x < getHeight() -1)
        {
            if(grid[x][y+1] == 1)       {neighbours++;} 
            if(grid[x][y-1] == 1)       {neighbours++;}
            if(grid[x+1][y] == 1)       {neighbours++;}
            if(grid[x+1][y+1] == 1)     {neighbours++;} 
            if(grid[x+1][y-1] == 1)     {neighbours++;}
        }
        else if(x >= 1 && x < getHeight() -1 && y == 0 && y < getWidth() -1)
        {
            if(grid[x][y+1] == 1)       {neighbours++;} 
            if(grid[x+1][y] == 1)       {neighbours++;}
            if(grid[x+1][y+1] == 1)     {neighbours++;} 
            if(grid[x-1][y+1] == 1)     {neighbours++;}
        }
        else if(x == getHeight() && y >= 1 && y < getWidth() - 1)
        {
            if(grid[x][y+1] == 1)       {neighbours++;} 
            if(grid[x][y-1] == 1)       {neighbours++;}
            if(grid[x-1][y-1] == 1)     {neighbours++;}
            if(grid[x-1][y+1] == 1)     {neighbours++;}
        }
        else if(x >=1 && x < getHeight() - 1 && y == getWidth() )
        {
            if(grid[x][y-1] == 1)       {neighbours++;}
            if(grid[x+1][y] == 1)       {neighbours++;}
            if(grid[x+1][y-1] == 1)     {neighbours++;}
            if(grid[x-1][y-1] == 1)     {neighbours++;}
        }
        else if(x == 0 && y == getWidth() )
        {   
            if(grid[x][y-1] == 1)       {neighbours++;}
            if(grid[x+1][y] == 1)       {neighbours++;}
            if(grid[x+1][y-1] == 1)     {neighbours++;}
        }
        else if(x == getHeight()  && y == 0)
        {
            if(grid[x-1][y] == 1)       {neighbours++;}
            if(grid[x][y+1] == 1)       {neighbours++;}
            if(grid[x-1][y+1] == 1)     {neighbours++;}
        }   
        else if(x == getHeight()  && y == getWidth() )
        {
            if(grid[x][y-1] == 1)       {neighbours++;}
            if(grid[x-1][y] == 1)       {neighbours++;}
            if(grid[x-1][y-1] == 1)     {neighbours++;}
        }
        return neighbours;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        int[][] newGrid;
        int[][] swap, old, New;
        int n;

        for(int i=0; i<grid.length; i++)
        {
            for(int j=0; j<grid[i].length; j++)
            {
                n = neighbours(i,j);
                old = grid;

                if(grid[i][j] == 1)
                {
                        if(n < 2)       {generation = 0;}
                    else if(n > 3)      {generation = 0;}
                    else if(n == 2)     {generation = 1; }
                }
                else
                {
                    if(n == 3)      {generation = 1;}
                    else
                            {generation = 0;}
                }

                if(generation == 1)
                {
                    New = old;
                    New[i][j] = 1;
                    swap = New;
                    newGrid = swap;
                    grid = newGrid;

                    show();

                    grid = old;
                }
                else
                {
                    New = old;
                    New[i][j] = 0; 
                                        swap = New;
                    newGrid = swap;
                                        grid = newGrid;

                                        show();

                                        grid = old;
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: please post the exception details and tell us where in the code the exception occurs.

Comment: Thank you for replying, these are the details: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10
 at LifeGrid.neighbours(LifeGrid.java:87)
 at LifeGrid.run(LifeGrid.java:150)
 at LifeGrid.main(LifeGrid.java:59)

Comment: Please edit the question with the details.

Comment: You might check [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8199460/issue-with-game-of-life/8200046#8200046) for tips.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's in the neighbours() method.  Those x++ or y++ should be x+1 or y+1 (and similarly for the x--).  Instead of checking 1 greater than x (or y) you're repeatedly incrementing it.

Comment: I have changed the code as you suggested, therefore from x++ to x+1 and same for x-- and y. However it still does not work giving me the same exception error.

Comment: Although I think this is the solution, line numbers would help greatly.

Comment: The other error is probably due to checking x and y against getWidth() and getHeight().  I think you should be checking against getWidth() - 1 and getHeight() - 1 since those return the actual length but the indices are one less.

Comment: Thank you very much! Now I do not get any errors from the exception but it does not compute any generation...

Answer (score 0):

To reiterate **dgunderson** with an example and a walkthrough:

```
//...

public int neighbours(int x, int y)
{
int neighbours = 0;

if(x >= 1 && y >= 1 && x < getHeight() && y < getWidth())
{
    if(grid[x][y++] == 1)       {neighbours++;} 
    if(grid[x][y--] == 1)       {neighbours++;}
    if(grid[x++][y] == 1)       {neighbours++;}
    if(grid[x++][y++] == 1)     {neighbours++;} 
    if(grid[x++][y--] == 1)     {neighbours++;}
    if(grid[x--][y--] == 1)     {neighbours++;}
    if(grid[x--][y++] == 1)     {neighbours++;}
}
//...
```

Let: getHeight() returns 6.

Let: getWidth() returns 10.

Let: x equal getHeight() - 1.

Let: y equal getWidth() - 1.

Therefore:

```
//...

public int neighbours(int x, int y)
{
int neighbours = 0;

//if 5 >= 1 && 9 >= 1 && 5 < 6 && 9 < 10...TRUE
if(x >= 1 && y >= 1 && x < getHeight() && y < getWidth())
{
    //if grid[5][9] == 1)  "increment y"  { "increment neighbors" };
    if(grid[x][y++] == 1)       {neighbours++;}
    //if grid[5][10] <-- WHUPS! out of bounds.
    if(grid[x][y--] == 1)       {neighbours++;}
    if(grid[x++][y] == 1)       {neighbours++;}
    if(grid[x++][y++] == 1)     {neighbours++;} 
    if(grid[x++][y--] == 1)     {neighbours++;}
    if(grid[x--][y--] == 1)     {neighbours++;}
    if(grid[x--][y++] == 1)     {neighbours++;}
}
//...
```

In addition, the call stack says the error specifically happens in neighbours and the only thing you are doing in neighbours is manipulate array indexes.