# Game Of Life Problems

Tags: java

I'm not sure if I'm going about this the right way, I've created my code which works for all "still life" cell arrangements, ie. Beehive, Block, Boat and Loaf. However, for arrangements that are supposed of be manipulated and involve the death and birth of cells I have problems.

Right now I'm creating cells first, and then killing off anyone's which fall into the rules (If the surrounding neighbours is a total less than or equal to one, equal to or greater than four).

What I have going now, doesn't work how it's supposed to. I'll include some images underneath my code:

```
public class Untitled {
    public static void main(String[] params){
        Life life = new Life();
        String[][] list = life.readGame();

        life.print(list);
        System.out.println();

        for(int i = 1; i <= 5; i++){
            list = life.run(list);
            life.print(list);
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}

class Life {
    public String[][] readGame(){
        String[][] array = {
                { "-","-", "-", "-", "-", "-","-"},
                { "-","-", "-", "-", "-", "-","-"},
                { "-","-", "-", "x", "-", "-","-"},
                { "-","-", "-", "x", "-", "-","-"},
                { "-","-", "-", "x", "-", "-","-"},
                { "-","-", "-", "-", "-", "-","-"},
                { "-","-", "-", "-", "-", "-","-"}
        };
        return array;
    }

    public void print(String[][] array){
        for(int x = 0; x < array.length; x++){
            for(int y = 0; y < array[x].length; y++){
                System.out.print(array[x][y]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public String[][] run(String[][] array){
        populateCells(array);
        System.out.println("Populated:\n");
        print(array);
        killCells(array);
        System.out.println("Killed:\n");
        print(array);
        return array;
    }

    public int amountOfNeighbors(String[][] array, int x, int y){
        int amount = 0;

        for(int x1 = -1; x1 <= 1; x1++){
            if(x + x1 >= 0 && x + x1 < array.length){
                for(int y1 = -1; y1 <= 1; y1++){
                    if(y + y1 >= 0 && y + y1 < array[x1 + x].length){
                        if(!(x1 == 0 && y1 == 0) && !array[x1 + x][y1 + y].equals("-")){ 
                            amount++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return amount;
    }

    public void populateCells(String[][] array){
        int neighbours;

        for(int x = 0; x < array.length; x++){
            for(int y = 0; y < array[x].length; y++){
                neighbours = amountOfNeighbors(array,x,y);

                if(neighbours == 3){
                    array[x][y] = "x";
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void killCells(String[][] array){
        int neighbours;

        for(int x = 0; x < array.length; x++){
            for(int y = 0; y < array[x].length; y++){
                neighbours = amountOfNeighbors(array,x,y);

                if(neighbours <= 1 || neighbours >= 4){
                    array[x][y] = "-";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As for the images, here's a simple blinker structure and what happens after population and deletion of cells:

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

Comment: possible duplicate of [The game of life(Conway's game) - how to check for cell neighbours](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8364301/the-game-of-lifeconways-game-how-to-check-for-cell-neighbours)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each time you call `run()` you need to create a copy of the original board, and use that copy to check the state of each cell as you modify the cells in the original board.

Otherwise, each time you update a cell you will be inadvertently changing the states of the cells around it.

This is a fairly common bug in simulations that involve game boards like Game of Life - so now you know to watch out for it :)

Comment: Or have 3rd and 4th states on the board to indicate should be removed or added.

Comment: ^ That would also work and is basically equivalent (+1). I would still encourage copying instead of having multiple states because then you can use the built-in array copy function instead of having to write custom state swap code.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "check the state of each cell as you modify the cells in the original board"?

Comment: @user1327636 sure - what i mean is that instead of calling amountOfNeighbors on the board that you will be modifying, you call it on the copy you created. does that make more sense?

Comment: So, in run(), I would create a copy of the board, call amountOfNeighbours() on that and then what should I do? (Sorry, this is all a bit new to me.)

Comment: @user1327636 no problem! The first part is right - you create a  copy in run(). Then you need to pass in two arrays to the populate and kill functions: `array`, which you already pass in, and `array_copy`. Then in populate and kill, call amountOfNeighbors on `array_copy` instead of `array`.

Comment: Why would I need to pass both the array and the copy into the populate and kill functions if I'm only going to do that to one of them?

(It'd probably be easier for me to understand if you gave me a step by step process of what should happen.)

Comment: @user1327636 i've modified the code here (only fixed for killCells - not populate): https://gist.github.com/cammckinnon/5000257. Note that you'll have to implement deep_copy yourself or figure out which Java function to use.

Comment: Oh okay, I understand now what to do. Thanks for the help!