# Java - the game of Life; problems with life detection

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, conways-game-of-life

I'm attempting the [Game of Life](http://www.bitstorm.org/gameoflife/) - what I'm stuck on is determining whether a space should be alive or dead based on the area around it. I'm at the point where I can't tell what I'm doing wrong - hopefully another set of eyes can help.

This is just a snippet, full code here: http://pastebin.com/ucYe653p

```
public static void updateMatrix(boolean[][] board, int[] birthLive) {

    //clone the board so modified values don't affect the results of upcoming spaces
    boolean[][] boardCopy = board.clone();
    for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++)
        boardCopy[i] = board[i].clone();

    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i < board.length - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < board[i].length - 1; j++) {

            //different requirements for dead or living pieces' living status
            if (board[i][j] == false) {

                //check the nine-by-nine square, starting at (-1, 1) and ending at (1, -1) where 0 is the affected location
                // * * *
                // * 0 *
                // * * *
                for (int ii = board[i - 1].length; ii < board[i + 1].length; ii++) {
                    for (int jj = board[j - 1].length; ii < board[j + 1].length; jj++) {
                        if (boardCopy[i][j] == true)
                            count++;
                    }
                }

                //check to see what high and low amt of required adjacent lifeforms is
                if (count >= birthLive[0] && count <= birthLive[1])
                    board[i][j] = true;
                else
                    board[i][j] = false;
                count = 0;

            }

            else {

                for (int ii = board[i - 1].length; ii < board[i + 1].length; ii++) {
                    for (int jj = board[j - 1].length; ii < board[j + 1].length; jj++) {
                        if (boardCopy[i][j] == true)
                            count++;
                    }
                }

                count -= 1; //For board[i][j] is always true
                if (count >= birthLive[2] && count <= birthLive[3])
                    board[i][j] = true;
                else
                    board[i][j] = false;
                count = 0;

            }

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you describe what the symptom of the problem is?

Comment: You need to give us an idea of what is going wrong. ie. What you expect this code to do, and what it does do.

Comment: Right, sorry. `To calculate whether an entity lives at a given cell for the next iteration, you will need to calculate the number of entities in the neighborhood and compare the count with the birth range (if the cell is empty) or live range (if there was already an entity there). Note that the count must be based on the values as of the previous iteration. This means that you will need to make a copy of the matrix before doing the updates so you can count entities in neighborhoods based on original values.` 


How it looks:

http://i.imgur.com/C0i4e.png

Comment: You might get some tips from [this code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8200046/418556).  The problem on that thread seems to be the same problem as here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're whole code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Update {

   public final static int ITERATIONS = 5;

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      System.out.println("This program will simulate the game of Life.");

      Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.println("Please input the size of your board.");

      System.out.println("Rows:");
      final int rows = console.nextInt();

      System.out.println("Columns:");
      final int columns = console.nextInt();

      System.out.println("Please enter a seed:");
      final long seed = console.nextLong();

      int[] birthLive = new int[4];
      boolean[][] board = new boolean[rows][columns];

      createMatrix(board, seed);

      birthAndLive(birthLive);

      for (int i = 0; i < ITERATIONS; i++) {
         printMatrix(board);
         updateMatrix(board, birthLive);
      }

   }

   public static void createMatrix(boolean[][] board, long seed) {

      Random seedBool = new Random(seed);

      for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
         for (int j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++) {
            board[i][j] = false;
         }
      }

      for (int i = 1; i < board.length - 1; i++) {
         for (int j = 1; j < board[i].length - 1; j++) {
            board[i][j] = seedBool.nextBoolean();
         }
      }

   }

   public static void birthAndLive(int[] birthLive) {

      Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.println("Please input the birth range and the live range:");

      System.out.println("Birth (Low):");
      birthLive[0] = console.nextInt();

      System.out.println("Birth (High):");
      birthLive[1] = console.nextInt();

      System.out.println("Live (Low):");
      birthLive[2] = console.nextInt();

      System.out.println("Live (High):");
      birthLive[3] = console.nextInt();

   }

   public static void printMatrix(boolean[][] board) {

      for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
         for (int j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++) {
            if (board[i][j] == false)
               System.out.print(" - ");
            else
               System.out.print(" # ");
         }
         System.out.println();
      }
      System.out.println();
   }

   public static void updateMatrix(boolean[][] board, int[] birthLive) {

      // clone the board so modified values don't affect the results of upcoming
      // spaces
      boolean[][] boardCopy = board.clone();
      for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++)
         boardCopy[i] = board[i].clone();

      int count = 0;

      for (int i = 1; i < board.length - 1; i++) {
         for (int j = 1; j < board[i].length - 1; j++) {

            // different requirements for dead or living pieces' living status
            if (board[i][j] == false) {

               // check the nine-by-nine square, starting at (-1, 1) and ending
               // at (1, -1) where 0 is the affected location
               // * * *
               // * 0 *
               // * * *
               for (int ii = board[i - 1].length; ii < board[i + 1].length; ii++) {
                  for (int jj = board[j - 1].length; ii < board[j + 1].length; jj++) {
                     if (boardCopy[i][j] == true)
                        count++;
                  }
               }

               // check to see what high and low amt of required adjacent
               // lifeforms is
               if (count >= birthLive[0] && count <= birthLive[1])
                  board[i][j] = true;
               else
                  board[i][j] = false;
               count = 0;

            }

            else {

               for (int ii = board[i - 1].length; ii < board[i + 1].length; ii++) {
                  for (int jj = board[j - 1].length; ii < board[j + 1].length; jj++) {
                     if (boardCopy[i][j] == true)
                        count++;
                  }
               }

               count -= 1; // For board[i][j] is always true
               if (count >= birthLive[2] && count <= birthLive[3])
                  board[i][j] = true;
               else
                  board[i][j] = false;
               count = 0;

            }

         }
      }

   }
}
```

You're setting your board[...] values in the body of the updateMatrix method and shouldn't be doing this as it will effect the calculations of neighboring cells prematurely. Instead only set the cloned array's cells in the body of this method. And then at the *end* of the method either iterate through the cloned board copying it's results into the original board or else return the cloned board and when calling the method use it to set its results into the board... i.e.,

```
board = updateMatrix(board, birthLive);
```

Comment: Yeah, this is definitely also a problem. All of those `board[i][j] = ...` `should be boardCopy[i][j] = ...`

Comment: I thought I was circumventing the effects of setting board values by using boardCopy to test for pos/neg instead of board, though? I think I updated it so I'm not using any changed values - http://pastebin.com/ucYe653p

Comment: Yeah, you're right, Noah--now that I look again, I think you were doing it right. Did fixing this solve your problem?

Comment: @Noah: yeah, you're right.  You were doing backwards from what I'm used to, but it would work as well if done with care. sorry. :(

Answer (score 1):

This loop/nested loop has `ii` in both of the conditional checks... second is probably supposed to be `jj`? Also, where are you referencing `ii` and `jj`? In the if, it's using `i` and `j` again.

```
  for (int ii = board[i - 1].length; ii < board[i + 1].length; ii++) {
                for (int jj = board[j - 1].length; ii < board[j + 1].length; jj++) {
                    if (boardCopy[i][j] == true)
                        count++;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Ah, good catch. I was just trying to use ii and jj to act as (-1, 1) - (1, -1) - I couldn't think of a good way to do that. I'll draw a diagram to try to explain what I mean. http://i.imgur.com/NMAW6.png

Comment: I understand what you're doing. It's just that you should say `if(boardCopy[ii][jj] == true)` instead, otherwise you're just checking the same value over and over.