# How to count live neighbours of a cell in Conway's Game of Life?

Tags: java, conways-game-of-life

I'm implementing Conway's game of life. I've read in the inittal board and now I need to program it to count live neighbors of a cell.

Some basic rules

> Any live cell with fewer than two live neighbours dies, as if caused by under-population.
>   Any live cell with two or three live neighbours lives on to the next generation.
>   Any live cell with more than three live neighbours dies, as if by overcrowding.
>   Any dead cell with exactly three live neighbours becomes a live cell, as if by reproduction.

Here is the code I have already.

UPDATE: This is code altered after some initial advice.

```
/**
 * Write your comments here following the javadoc conventions
 */
public static int countNeighbours(boolean[][] board, int row, int col)
{
    int neighbours = 0; 
    int x = -1;
    while (x <= 1) {
        int y = -1;
        while (y <= 1) {
            if (board[row][col] == true) {

                neighbours++; 
            }
            // Given a 2D boolan array and a cell location given by its
            // row and column indecies, count the number of live cells
            // immediately surrounding the given cell. Remember that you
            // mustn't count the cell itself.

        }


    }
    return neighbours;
}
```

Is this on the right track?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ This should help you...

Comment: See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8199460/issue-with-game-of-life/8200046#8200046).

Comment: One thing is helping with an error, another very different is giving you the code so you can skip learning (that is the reason of the exercise, your prof really does not need 100 copies of that program each year).

Comment: @SJuan76 I don't understand the issue? No one has given me code? I was just pointed in the right direction and then went away and figured it out. And one of the best ways to learn is by asking more experienced programmers for advice. Not all of us are experts in Java.

Comment: Please accept one of the answers as an answer to your question and upvote if it help you. It is the least you can do when somebody invests time in helping you out. You have asked six questions and received answers to them all, but never  accepted one of them.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to do

```
if (board[row][col] == true) {
```

Which is the same than

```
if (board[row][col]) {
```

Answer (score 2):

Since I know this is an typical school-assignment I want give you the full answer but you should not redifine row in the start of the method, call it something else, and the loops should go from `row-1` to `row+1` and `col-1` to `col+1`.

Answer (score 0):

If you can make your board global, this might work for a single cell with wrap-around:

```
public Cell[] getNeighbours(int i, int j) {
int i2 = i - 1, i3 = i + 1, j2 = j - 1, j3 = j + 1;
if (i2 == -1) i2 = board.length - 1;
if (i3 == (board.length)) i3 = 0;
if (j2 == -1) j2 = board[i].length - 1;
if (j3 == (board[i].length)) j3 = 0;
return new Cell[]{board[i2][j2], board[i2][j], board[i2][j3], board[i][j2], board[i][j3], board[i3][j2], board[i3][j], board[i3][j3]};
```

}

Then just count how many of these Cells are alive and return that.