# 2D arrays and Game of Life

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, conways-game-of-life

Game of Life -- I can't quite understand how to properly check for neighbors..

Can anyone tell me why my right border and top border arn't acting properly, that is anything placed in them is deleted? For instance if I placed a glider that hits the right border it creates a square one column before the last instead of creating a square that includes the last column, and if I place a glider that hits the top it creates a square including the top row but it also continues onto the bottom row. A glider that hits the left border or bottom border though creates a square either including the left column or the bottom row (respectively). Here's the algorithms that are making the difference...I'm using a grid that's 75x75 that's why there are constants

```
    public class Grid{

    private int columns;
    private int rows;
    private Cell[][] grid;

    public Grid(int column, int row){
      this.columns = column;
      this.rows = row;
        grid = new Cell[row][column];
      for (int r = 0; r < row; r++){
        for (int c = 0; c < column; c++){
         grid[r][c] = new Cell(r,c);
       }
     }
    }

  public boolean getCell(int r, int c){
    return this.grid[r][c].isCellAlive();
  }

  public void giveCellLife(int r, int c){
   this.grid[r][c].setCell(true);
  }

  public void killCell(int r, int c){
    this.grid[r][c].setCell(false);
  }

  public void nextGridState(){
    cellNeighbors();
    for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++){
      for (int c = 0; c < columns; c++){
        if (grid[r][c].isCellAlive()  && grid[r][c].getNeighbors() < 2){
          grid[r][c].setCell(false);
        }
        if (grid[r][c].isCellAlive()  && grid[r][c].getNeighbors() > 3){
          grid[r][c].setCell(false);
        }
        if (!grid[r][c].isCellAlive()  && grid[r][c].getNeighbors() == 3){
          grid[r][c].setCell(true);
        }
      }
    }
    reset();
  }

  public void reset(){            
    for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++){
      for (int c = 0; c < columns; c++){ 
        grid[r][c].removeNeighbors();
      } 
    }
  }





  public void cellNeighbors(){
    for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++){
     for (int c = 0; c < columns; c++){ 
       try {
         if (grid[r-1][c+1].isCellAlive() == true){
           grid[r][c].addNeighbor();
         }
         if (grid[r][c+1].isCellAlive() == true){
           grid[r][c].addNeighbor();
         }
         if (grid[r+1][c+1].isCellAlive() == true){
           grid[r][c].addNeighbor();
         }
         if (grid[r-1][c].isCellAlive() == true){
           grid[r][c].addNeighbor();
         }
         if (grid[r+1][c].isCellAlive() == true){
           grid[r][c].addNeighbor();
         }
         if (grid[r-1][c-1].isCellAlive() == true){
           grid[r][c].addNeighbor();
         }
         if (grid[r][c-1].isCellAlive() == true){
          grid[r][c].addNeighbor();
         }
         if (grid[r+1][c-1].isCellAlive() == true){
           grid[r][c].addNeighbor();
         }
       } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
       }

       if (r == 0){
         try {
         if (grid[r][c+1].isCellAlive() == true){
           grid[r][c].addNeighbor();
         }
         if (grid[r][c-1].isCellAlive() == true){
           grid[r][c].addNeighbor();
         }
         if (grid[r+74][c+1].isCellAlive() == true){
           grid[r][c].addNeighbor();
         }
         if (grid[r+74][c-1].isCellAlive() == true){
           grid[r][c].addNeighbor();
         }
         if (grid[r+74][c].isCellAlive() == true){
           grid[r][c].addNeighbor();
         }
         if (grid[r+1][c+1].isCellAlive() == true){
           grid[r][c].addNeighbor();
         }
         if (grid[r+1][c].isCellAlive() == true){
          grid[r][c].addNeighbor();
         }
         if (grid[r+1][c-1].isCellAlive() == true){
           grid[r][c].addNeighbor();
         }
       } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
       }
       }

       if (c == 74){
         try {
         if (grid[r-1][c-1].isCellAlive() == true){
           grid[r][c].addNeighbor();
         }
         if (grid[r][c-1].isCellAlive() == true){
           grid[r][c].addNeighbor();
         }
         if (grid[r+1][c-1].isCellAlive() == true){
           grid[r][c].addNeighbor();
         }
         if (grid[r-1][c].isCellAlive() == true){
           grid[r][c].addNeighbor();
         }
         if (grid[r+1][c].isCellAlive() == true){
           grid[r][c].addNeighbor();
         }
         if (grid[r-1][0].isCellAlive() == true){
           grid[r][c].addNeighbor();
         }
         if (grid[r][0].isCellAlive() == true){
          grid[r][c].addNeighbor();
         }
         if (grid[r+1][0].isCellAlive() == true){
           grid[r][c].addNeighbor();
         }
       } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
       }
       }


     }
    }
  }
}   

public class Cell{

  private int x;
  private int y;
  public int neighbors;
  private boolean living;

  public Cell(int x, int y){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    neighbors = 0;
    living = false;
  }

  public int getNeighbors(){
    return this.neighbors;
  }

  public void addNeighbor(){
    neighbors++;
  }

  public void removeNeighbors(){
    neighbors = 0;
  }

  public boolean isCellAlive(){
    return this.living;
  }

  public void setCell(boolean isCellAlive){
    this.living = isCellAlive;
  }



}
```

I've looked at this for hours now, another pair of eyes would really be nice =)
Thanks

Edit ** here's a screenie of the problems...

[image]

Comment: Does your grid wrap?  What exactly does "not acting properly" mean?  Do you have a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)?  As a sidenote, in a conditional expression you do not have to check `if (expression == true)`... it is sufficient to just check `if (expression)` and likewise when checking for false you just do `if (!expression)`.

Comment: ok there's a screenshot =)

Comment: Compare yours to this [working example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8200046/418556) & you might spot the error.  If not, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) (like the linked code).