# What's the idea behind using Thread.Join() in this case?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a code of a small Java program which generates MD5 checksums. It can work only with one file at a time. When given a file name it opens a modal dialog where it shows the progress bar and the overall status. At "100%" this dialog closes, the program displays generated MD5 and then is ready to take another file.

The function which generates MD5 is located in the class which implements `Runnable` and this class is then passed to `Thread` instance. Then this `Thread` object is used as `thread.start(); thread.join()`. The program works with only one file at a time. It works perfectly well when I use the function without threads.

My question is: what's the purpose of placing it in a separate thread and joining it?

Comment: "I have a code of a small Java program which generates MD5 checksums" It'd be easier to work out the idea if you showed the code.

Comment: When you work with other people's code, don't necessarily assume they knew what they were doing. But without being able to even look at the code I would assume that multithreading is used so the progress can be updated while the checksum generation thread is running.

Comment: There is never any good reason (except maybe for testing/experimenting/learning) to write `t.start();` followed immediately by `t.join();` with nothing in between.  But you haven't shown us the code.  Is that really what it does?  In the application that you describe, there is a very good reason to have the checksum calculated in a different thread from the one that animates the progress bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I have already mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21332027/3227787), if you keep time-consuming tasks in the main GUI process of your program you should be aware that it will not respond to any user interaction as long as the task is running.

In [this page](http://www.kdgregory.com/index.php?page=swing.async) you can find some good practices regarding asynchronous operations in Java applications (it is focused on Swing, but can be applied broadly for other Java coding strategies). I would like to highlight one of the topics:

> **Rule #2: do not run time-consuming operations on the event thread.**
>
> I'll keep repeating this: Swing uses a single thread for all GUI events. If your event handler is uploading a multi-megabyte file across the net, those events will be delayed until you're done. There is a balancing act involved with this rule: some operations (such as getting the size of a file) are so fast that they won't interrupt the user. However, that's not a reason to be cavalier, because some day your user will be getting the size of a file that resides on a fileserver that has an intermittent network connection.

As you have mentioned, the dialog is kept opened while the MD5 is being generated. That should be the reason why the developer used a separate thread -- even knowing the program can only handle one file at a time, by keeping the computation isolated in its own thread will avoid the main GUI from being frozen while the MD5 is computed.

However, [**`Thread.join()` allows one thread to wait for the completion of another**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/join.html). That said, the developer may have used this strategy to **prevent additional user interaction** until the MD5 calculation is complete. Or, what is also possible, to **wait for the MD5 calculation to finish before the main program (or GUI) finishes (closes)**.

Comment: Oh, thanx, Bruno Toffolo. That's just what I wanted to know!

Comment: Glad to know it helped! :)

Comment: But if the main GUI "process" (thread right?) forks the MD5 thread and then waits for it with `thread.join()` then it might as well call the MD5 method directly right?

Comment: In this case, yes. The `thread.join()` call would establish a dependency that is equal to sequentially calling the method directly -- in fact, calling it directly would be even faster in terms of performance because it would not have the entire overhead of creating and killing a new thread. **Unless** there is more than a thread involved, as you mentioned in your answer, what would be a much more practical use case for the threading strategy.

Answer (score 1):

> Then this Thread object is used as thread.start(); thread.join().

Is it really doing something like:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new MD5ProcessorRunnable(...));
thread.start();
thread.join();
...
```

This is a very strange pattern if so.  There is no reason why the code couldn't call the MD5 processor directly in the current thread.

I suspect that it is doing something equivalent to:

```
MD5ProcessorRunnable processor = new MD5ProcessorRunnable(...);
Thread progressBarThread = new Thread(new ProgressBar(processor));
progressBarThread.start();
Thread md5Thread = new Thread(processor);
md5Thread.start();
md5Thread.join();
progressBarThread.join();
...
```

This starts a thread which updates the progress bar and only returns GUI control to the user once *both* threads complete.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the code, my guess is one thread calculates the checksum and the other handles the progress bar, updating its value when necessary, but you need to add the code to your post to let us help you.

The join method allows one thread to wait for the completion of another, so it's the way to finish the execution of the application ensuring both threads end

Comment: Does Thread.join() suspend the execution of the thread from which it was called? Is that suspended thread still able to update progress bar?

Answer (score 0):

`Thread.join()` is defined as the following:

> Waits for this thread to die.

Thread joins are usually used to make the main thread wait for other threads to finish their processes. Of course this is assuming the join was called from the main thread.

I am guessing the code blocks user interaction until the MD5 calculation is complete.