# Conway's Game of Life Simulation - Drawing issue

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, paint

I'm creating a Conway's Game of Life simulation and I'm running into a problem that I can't seem to figure out. I can't seem to get my `JPanel` to update on each iteration. I have a feeling it is something simple that I'm overlooking but any help would be greatly appreciated. Basically the first frame gets rendered but after that, the panel does not repaint.

Here is my code:

### GameOfLife.java

```
import javax.swing.JFrame; 
public class GameOfLife {


    private Board currentBoard;
    private Board nextBoard;
    private int generation = 0;
    private JFrame currentFrame;

    public GameOfLife() {
        currentBoard = new Board(200, 100);
        nextBoard = new Board(currentBoard.getXSize(), currentBoard.getYSize());
        currentBoard.populate();

    }

    public void step() {
        generation++;
        System.out.println(generation);
        nextBoard.clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < currentBoard.getXSize(); i++) {
              for (int j = 0; j < currentBoard.getYSize(); j++) {
                if(currentBoard.getAt(i, j) == true && (currentBoard.numNeighbors(i, j) == 2 || currentBoard.numNeighbors(i, j) == 3))  {
                    nextBoard.setAlive(i, j);
                }
                else if (currentBoard.getAt(i, j) == false && currentBoard.numNeighbors(i, j) == 3){
                    nextBoard.setAlive(i, j);
                }
              }
        }

        //System.out.println(nextBoard.toString());
        //System.out.println(currentBoard.toString());

        currentBoard = nextBoard.copy();
        currentBoard.repaint();


    }

    public Board getBoard() {
        return currentBoard;
    }

    public void setFrame(Board panel) {
        currentFrame.setContentPane(panel);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        GameOfLife game = new GameOfLife();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        game.currentFrame = frame;
        frame.setContentPane(game.getBoard());
        frame.setSize(game.getBoard().getWidth(), game.getBoard().getHeight());
        frame.setVisible(true);

        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            game.step();
            Thread.sleep(5);
        }

    }   
}
```

### Board.java

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.util.Random;
/*
 * Board for Game of Life
 */

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Board extends JPanel{

    private boolean[][] board;
    private int xSize;
    private int ySize;
    private final int CELL_SIZE = 5;
    private ArrayList<String> alive;
    private Random rand = new Random();
    private final double SPAWN_CHANCE = .4;

    public Board(int xSize, int ySize) {
        this.xSize = xSize;
        this.ySize = ySize;
        board = new boolean[xSize][ySize];
        alive = new ArrayList<String>();
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
        for (int i = 0; i < xSize; i++) {
              for (int j = 0; j < ySize; j++) {
                if(board[i][j]) {
                    g2d.fillRect(CELL_SIZE*i, CELL_SIZE*j, CELL_SIZE, CELL_SIZE);
                }
                else {
                    g2d.drawRect(CELL_SIZE*i, CELL_SIZE*j, CELL_SIZE, CELL_SIZE);
                }
              }
        }

    }

    public void clear() {
        for (int i = 0; i < xSize; i++) {
              for (int j = 0; j < ySize; j++) {
                board[i][j] = false;
              }
        }

    }

    public void populate() {
        for (int i = 0; i < xSize; i++) {
              for (int j = 0; j < ySize; j++) {
                if(rand.nextDouble() < SPAWN_CHANCE) {
                    board[i][j] = true;
                    alive.add(i+","+j);
                }
              }
        }
    }

    public void setAlive(int x, int y) {
        board[x][y] = true;
        alive.add(x+","+y);
    }

    public int numNeighbors(int row, int col) {

            int neighbors = 0;             

            for (int x = Math.max(0,row-1); x < Math.min(row+2,xSize); x++) {
                for (int y = Math.max(0,col-1); y < Math.min(col+2,ySize); y++) {
                        if (board[x][y]) {
                            neighbors ++;

                        }
                }
            }
        //System.out.println("Num Neighbors for " + row + "," + col + ": " + neighbors);
        return neighbors;
    }

    public Board copy() {
        Board newBoard = new Board(xSize, ySize);
        for(int i = 0; i < board.length; i++)
            for(int j = 0; j < board[0].length; j++) {
                if(this.getAt(i, j)) {
                    newBoard.setAlive(i, j);
                }
            }
        return newBoard;
    }

    public int getWidth() {
            return xSize*CELL_SIZE;
    }

    public int getHeight() {
        return ySize*CELL_SIZE;
    }

    public int getXSize() {
        return xSize;
    }
    public int getYSize() {
        return ySize;
    }

    public boolean getAt(int x, int y) {
        return board[x][y];
    }

    public String toString() {
        String toReturn = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < xSize; i++) {
              for (int j = 0; j < ySize; j++) {
                if(board[i][j]) {
                    toReturn += "X";
                }
                else {
                    toReturn += "O";
                }
              }
              toReturn += "\n";
        }
        return toReturn;
    }

}
```

Comment: See also this [working version](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8200046/418556).

Answer (score 1):

If we take a look at `Board#copy` we can see you are creating a brand new copy/instance of `Board`...

```
public Board copy() {
    Board newBoard = new Board(xSize, ySize);
    for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < board[0].length; j++) {
            if (this.getAt(i, j)) {
                newBoard.setAlive(i, j);
            }
        }
    }
    return newBoard;
}
```

But this is never added to the screen, so it can never be displayed.

Don't create a "copy" of the board, but instead, update the information which the `Board` is suppose to display.

Comment: The problem is that if I update the grid that is active, it messes up the numNeighbors function. I therefore need to create the next generation on a separate board and then once all the calculations are complete, render either that board or somehow copy the data of the new board to the old one.

Comment: No, you don't. You need to figure out how to fix the numNeighbors function