# Conway's Game of Life Debugging (Java)

Tags: java, debugging, matrix, conways-game-of-life

I'm trying to get my Conway's Game of Life to run correctly, but I keep getting incorrect results, and I can't seem to figure out the problem. Here's my code for executing the generations of Game of Life:

```
public void generate(int gen)
 {
   generations = gen;
   int count = 0;
   for (int x = 0; x < generations; x++)
   {
      //Copies array to temp
      for (int row = 0; row < 20; row++)
      {
         for (int col = 0; col < 20; col++)
         {
            temp[row][col] = mat[row][col];
         }
      }

      //Gets count of living organisms surrounding
      for (int row = 0; row < 20; row++)
      {
         for (int col = 0; col < 20; col++)
         {
            count = check(row, col);

            //determines life or death
            if (temp[row][col] == false)
            {
               if (count == 3)
               {
                  mat[row][col] = true;
               }
            }
            else
            {
               if (count > 3 || count < 2)
               {
                  mat[row][col] = false;
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }

   displayGrid();
 }

 //Checks the number of living organisms in adjacent cells
 public int check(int row, int col)
 {
   int count = 0;
   for (int r = -1; r < 2; r++)
   {
      for (int c = -1; c < 2; c++)
      {
         if (isLegal((row + r),(col + c)) && temp[row + r][col + c] == true)
         {
            count++;
         }
      }
   }
   return count;
 }

 //Checks whether an adjacent space is in the array 
 public boolean isLegal(int row, int col)
 {
   if (row > 19 || row < 0 || col > 19 || col < 0)
   {
      return false;
   }
   return true;
 }
```

Is there something fundamentally wrong with the way I'm trying to code this program?

Comment: Did you attach a debugger and walk through the flow of execution?

Comment: See also this [working version](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8200046/418556) that shows typical GoL behavior.

Answer (score 1):

in you `check()` method you include the square at `row` `col` in the total, when it should be ignoring it.

Comment: I updated the `check()` method to this:
    if (c != 0 && r != 0 && isLegal((row + r),(col + c)) && temp[row + r][col + c]     == true)
    {
    count++;       
}

But now it's outputting this something else incorrect.

@vandale