# How do I add a feature where I can get the generation in my game of life program?

Tags: java, swing, iteration, increment, conways-game-of-life

I'm trying to make my program display (testing in console first) the count number at each step where the cell changes its form. So the count should start from 0 and increment each time the cell changes its form. I tried this, using count++ however it doesn't increment by 1 but instead gives me random numbers. Any help will be much appreciated.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class GameOfLife extends javax.swing.JFrame {

final int wid = 100, hei = 50;
public static int count;
boolean[][] currentMove = new boolean[hei][wid], nextMove = new boolean[hei][wid];
boolean play;
Image offScrImg;
Graphics offScrGraph;

public GameOfLife() {
    initComponents();
    offScrImg = createImage(jPanel1.getWidth(), jPanel1.getHeight());
    offScrGraph = offScrImg.getGraphics();
    Timer time = new Timer();
    TimerTask task = new TimerTask(){
        public void run(){
            if(play){
                System.out.println(count);
                for(int i = 0; i < hei; i++){
                    for(int j = 0; j < wid; j++){
                        nextMove[i][j] = decide(i,j);

                    }
                }
                for(int i = 0; i < hei; i++){
                    for(int j = 0; j < wid; j++){
                        currentMove[i][j] = nextMove[i][j];

                    }
                }
                repain();
            }
        }
    };
    time.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 0, 100);
    repain();
}

private boolean decide(int i, int j){
    int neighbors = 0;

    // top-left row-1,col-1

    if (currentMove[getTopRow(i - 1)][getLeftCol(j - 1)]) neighbors++;  //Uses getTopRow and getLeftCol methods to determine the indices of the top left cell

    // left row,col-1
    if (currentMove[i][getLeftCol(j - 1)]) neighbors++;

    // bottom left row+1,col-1
    if (currentMove[getBottomRow(i + 1)][getLeftCol(j - 1)] ) neighbors++;

    // bottom row+1,col
    if (currentMove[getBottomRow(i + 1)][j]) neighbors++;

    // bottom right row+1,col+1
    if (currentMove[getBottomRow(i + 1)][getRightCol(j + 1)]) neighbors++;

    // right row,col+1
    if (currentMove[i][getRightCol(j + 1)]) neighbors++;

    // top-right row-1,col+1
    if (currentMove[getTopRow(i - 1)][getRightCol(j + 1)])neighbors++;

    // top row-1, col
    if(currentMove[getTopRow(i - 1)][j]) neighbors++;


    if(neighbors == 3) {       
        count++;
        return true;                
    }
    if(currentMove[i][j] && neighbors == 2){   
        count++;
        return true;         
    }
    return false;
}
private int getLeftCol(int neighbourCol) {
    return neighbourCol < 0 ? (wid-1) : neighbourCol;   //If the index of leftCol is less than 0, it uses the right most col (columns - 1)
}

private int getRightCol(int neighbourCol) {
    return neighbourCol > (wid-1) ? 0 : neighbourCol;
}

private int getTopRow(int neighbourRow) {
    return neighbourRow < 0 ? (hei - 1) : neighbourRow; //If the index of topRow is less than 0, it uses the bottom last row (rows - 1)
}

private int getBottomRow(int neighbourRow) {
    return neighbourRow > (hei - 1) ? 0 : neighbourRow;
}

private void repain(){
    offScrGraph.setColor(Color.RED);
    offScrGraph.fillRect(0, 0, jPanel1.getWidth(), jPanel1.getHeight());
    for(int i = 0 ; i < hei ; i++){
        for(int j = 0 ; j < wid; j++){
            if(currentMove[i][j]){
                offScrGraph.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                int x = j * jPanel1.getWidth()/wid;
                int y = i * jPanel1.getHeight()/hei;
                offScrGraph.fillRect(x, y, jPanel1.getWidth()/wid, jPanel1.getHeight()/hei);
            }
        }
    }
    offScrGraph.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    for(int i = 1; i < hei;i++){
        int y = i * jPanel1.getHeight()/hei;
        offScrGraph.drawLine(0, y, jPanel1.getWidth(), y);
    }
    for(int j = 1; j < wid;j++){
        int x = j * jPanel1.getWidth()/wid;
        offScrGraph.drawLine(x, 0, x, jPanel1.getHeight());
    }
    jPanel1.getGraphics().drawImage(offScrImg, 0, 0, jPanel1);
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">//GEN-BEGIN:initComponents
private void initComponents() {

    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jPanel1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(102, 102, 102));
    jPanel1.addMouseMotionListener(new java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter() {
        public void mouseDragged(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            jPanel1MouseDragged(evt);
        }
    });
    jPanel1.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            jPanel1MouseClicked(evt);
        }
    });
    jPanel1.addComponentListener(new java.awt.event.ComponentAdapter() {
        public void componentResized(java.awt.event.ComponentEvent evt) {
            jPanel1ComponentResized(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
    jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
    jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            );
    jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 293, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            );

    jButton1.setText("Play");
    jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton2.setText("Reset");
    jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                    .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 81, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 323, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                    .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 81, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                    .addContainerGap())
            );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()
                    .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(jButton1)
                            .addComponent(jButton2))
                    .addContainerGap())
            );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>//GEN-END:initComponents

private void jPanel1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_jPanel1MouseClicked

}//GEN-LAST:event_jPanel1MouseClicked

private void jPanel1ComponentResized(java.awt.event.ComponentEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_jPanel1ComponentResized
    offScrImg = createImage(jPanel1.getWidth(), jPanel1.getHeight());
    offScrGraph = offScrImg.getGraphics();
    repain();
}//GEN-LAST:event_jPanel1ComponentResized

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_jButton1ActionPerformed
    play = !play;
    if(play) jButton1.setText("Pause");
    else jButton1.setText("Play");
    repain();
}//GEN-LAST:event_jButton1ActionPerformed

private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_jButton2ActionPerformed
    currentMove = new boolean[hei][wid];
    repain();
}//GEN-LAST:event_jButton2ActionPerformed

private void jPanel1MouseDragged(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_jPanel1MouseDragged
    int j = wid * evt.getX() / jPanel1.getWidth();
    int i = hei * evt.getY() / jPanel1.getHeight();
    if(SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(evt)){
        currentMove[i][j] = true;
    }else currentMove[i][j] = false;
    repain();
}//GEN-LAST:event_jPanel1MouseDragged

public static void main(String args[]) {
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(GameOfLife.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(GameOfLife.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(GameOfLife.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(GameOfLife.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new GameOfLife().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify//GEN-BEGIN:variables
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
// End of variables declaration//GEN-END:variables
}
```

Comment: @AndrewThompson Done

Comment: I used repain because there is already a built in method called repaint. So didn't want to clash.

Comment: Nice edit. :) BTW - Have not looked closely at your code, but checked that [this code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8200046/418556) could implement a generation counter in a handful of lines of code. Would it be helpful for you to see that?

Comment: @AndrewThompson Yes please. Appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 1):

This is how it can be done using a [related code example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8200046/418556).

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class GameOfLife extends JPanel {

    private int row, col;
    private boolean isLiving;
    private static int generation = 0;

    public static Random random = new Random();

    public GameOfLife(int r, int c) {
        this.row = r;
        this.col = c;
        MouseListener listener = new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                isLiving = !isLiving;
                repaint();
            }
        };
        this.addMouseListener(listener);
        isLiving = random.nextBoolean();
    }

    public boolean isAlive(int neighbors) {
        boolean alive = false;
        if (this.isLiving) {
            if (neighbors < 2) {
                alive = false;
            } else if (neighbors == 2 || neighbors == 3) {
                alive = true;
            } else if (neighbors > 3) {
                alive = false;
            }
        } else {
            if (neighbors == 3) {
                alive = true;
            }
        }
        return alive;
    }

    public void setAlive(boolean alive) {
        isLiving = alive;
    }

    public boolean isLiving() {
        return this.isLiving;
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if (this.isLiving) {
            g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth() - 1, getHeight() - 1);
        } else {
            g.drawRect(0, 0, getWidth() - 1, getHeight() - 1);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int s = 40;
        JPanel ui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(4, 4));
        final JLabel generationLabel = new JLabel("0", JLabel.CENTER);
        ui.add(generationLabel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

        final GameOfLife[][] biosphere = new GameOfLife[s][s];
        final JPanel gui = new JPanel(new GridLayout(s, s, 2, 2));
        ui.add(gui);
        for (int ii = 0; ii < s; ii++) {
            for (int jj = 0; jj < s; jj++) {
                GameOfLife cell = new GameOfLife(ii, jj);
                cell.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(10, 10));
                gui.add(cell);
                biosphere[ii][jj] = cell;
            }
        }

        ActionListener al = new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                boolean[][] living = new boolean[s][s];
                for (int ii = 0; ii < s; ii++) {
                    for (int jj = 0; jj < s; jj++) {
                        int top = (jj > 0 ? jj - 1 : s - 1);
                        int btm = (jj < s - 1 ? jj + 1 : 0);
                        int lft = (ii > 0 ? ii - 1 : s - 1);
                        int rgt = (ii < s - 1 ? ii + 1 : 0);
                        int neighbors = 0;
                        if (biosphere[ii][top].isLiving()) {
                            neighbors++;
                        }
                        if (biosphere[ii][btm].isLiving()) {
                            neighbors++;
                        }
                        if (biosphere[lft][top].isLiving()) {
                            neighbors++;
                        }
                        if (biosphere[lft][btm].isLiving()) {
                            neighbors++;
                        }
                        if (biosphere[lft][jj].isLiving()) {
                            neighbors++;
                        }
                        if (biosphere[rgt][jj].isLiving()) {
                            neighbors++;
                        }
                        if (biosphere[rgt][top].isLiving()) {
                            neighbors++;
                        }
                        if (biosphere[rgt][btm].isLiving()) {
                            neighbors++;
                        }
                        living[ii][jj] = biosphere[ii][jj].isAlive(neighbors);
                    }
                }
                for (int ii = 0; ii < s; ii++) {
                    for (int jj = 0; jj < s; jj++) {
                        biosphere[ii][jj].setAlive(living[ii][jj]);
                    }
                }
                generationLabel.setText("Generation: " + generation++);
                gui.repaint();
            }
        };

        Timer timer = new Timer(50, al);
        timer.start();

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ui);
        timer.stop();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you must get an error. You never initialise your counter.
Change

```
public static int count;
```

to

```
public static int count = 0;
```

and try what happens

Answer (score 0):

Here's the way I've implemented it before, I use 2 boolean arrays to check the current state of the board and save it to a new array, then copy the new array values to the current state array and repaint the board:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSlider;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

public class GameOfLife {

    public static final int ROWS = 30;
    public static final int COLS = 30;

    private JFrame frame;
    private JPanel pane;
    private Cell[][] cells;
    private boolean[][] currentState;
    private boolean[][] newState;
    private boolean isAlive = false;
    private JButton startButton;
    private JButton stopButton;
    private Timer timer;
    private JSlider slider;
    private JLabel label;
    private int interations;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new GameOfLife().createAndShowGui());
    }

    public void randomGeneration() {
        Random r = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++) {
                currentState[i][j] = r.nextBoolean();
                cells[i][j].setAlive(currentState[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }

    public void createAndShowGui() {
        frame = new JFrame(getClass().getSimpleName());     

        slider = new JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL, 0, 1000, 500);

        slider.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                timer.setDelay(slider.getValue());
            }
        });

        label = new JLabel("Number of iterations: " + interations);

        timer = new Timer(slider.getValue(), listener);
        timer.setInitialDelay(slider.getValue());

        pane = new JPanel(new GridLayout(ROWS, COLS));

        cells = new Cell[ROWS][COLS];
        currentState = new boolean[ROWS][COLS];
        newState = new boolean[ROWS][COLS];

        startButton = new JButton("Start");
        stopButton = new JButton("Stop");

        for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++) {
                currentState[i][j] = false;
                newState[i][j] = false;

                isAlive = currentState[i][j];
                cells[i][j] = new Cell(isAlive);

                cells[i][j].setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
                cells[i][j].addMouseListener(mouseListener);
                pane.add(cells[i][j]);
            }
        }

        startButton.addActionListener(listener);
        stopButton.addActionListener(listener);

        frame.add(slider, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.add(pane);
        frame.add(startButton, BorderLayout.WEST);
        frame.add(stopButton, BorderLayout.EAST);
        frame.add(label, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        randomGeneration();

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    public void updateState(int i, int j) {
        currentState[i][j] = !currentState[i][j];

        cells[i][j].setAlive(currentState[i][j]);
        cells[i][j].repaint();
    }

    ActionListener listener = new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (e.getSource().equals(startButton)) {
                if (!timer.isRunning()) {
                    timer.start();
                } else {
                    timer.restart();
                }
            } else if (e.getSource().equals(stopButton)) {
                timer.stop();
            } else {
                for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++) {
                        int neighbors = 0;

                        if (i - 1 > 0) {
                            if (j - 1 > 0) {
                                if (currentState[i - 1][j - 1]) {
                                    neighbors++;
                                }
                            }
                            if (j + 1 < COLS) {
                                if (currentState[i - 1][j + 1]) {
                                    neighbors++;
                                }
                            }
                            if (currentState[i - 1][j]) {
                                neighbors++;
                            }
                        }
                        if (i + 1 < ROWS) {
                            if (j - 1 > 0) {
                                if (currentState[i + 1][j - 1]) {
                                    neighbors++;
                                }
                            }
                            if (j + 1 < COLS) {
                                if (currentState[i + 1][j + 1]) {
                                    neighbors++;
                                }
                            }
                            if (currentState[i + 1][j]) {
                                neighbors++;
                            }
                        }
                        if (j - 1 > 0) {
                            if (currentState[i][j - 1]) {
                                neighbors++;
                            }
                        }
                        if (j + 1 < COLS) {
                            if (currentState[i][j + 1]) {
                                neighbors++;
                            }
                        }

                        if (currentState[i][j]) {
                            if (neighbors < 2 || neighbors >= 4) {
                                newState[i][j] = false;
                            } else {
                                newState[i][j] = true;
                            }
                        } else {
                            if (neighbors == 3) {
                                newState[i][j] = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++) {
                        currentState[i][j] = newState[i][j];
                        cells[i][j].setAlive(currentState[i][j]);
                        cells[i][j].revalidate();
                        cells[i][j].repaint();
                    }
                }

                interations++;
                label.setText("Number of iterations: " + interations);
                pane.revalidate();
                pane.repaint();
            }
        }
    };

    MouseListener mouseListener = new MouseListener() {



        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++) {
                    if (e.getSource().equals(cells[i][j])) {
                        updateState(i, j);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class Cell extends JPanel {
    private boolean isAlive;

    public Cell(boolean isAlive) {
        this.isAlive = isAlive;
    }

    public boolean isAlive() {
        return isAlive;
    }

    public void setAlive(boolean isAlive) {
        this.isAlive = isAlive;
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(20, 20);
    }

    @Override
    public Color getBackground() {
        return isAlive ? Color.GREEN : Color.GRAY;
    }
}
```

It also includes a `JSlider` to manage processing speed:

[image]

Have fun and notice that I used a [Swing Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) instead of the [Util Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) you're using.