# Having trouble making the JPanels inside Jgrid react to change immediately

Tags: java, swing, conways-game-of-life

I am currently attempting to write John Conway's game of life in java using Swing. I have however run into problems regarding `JPanel` cells in `GridLayout`. Here is the code that is problematic

```
    GameOfLifeFrame(int size, int generations, Random random, boolean[][] grid, final GameOfLife life) {
    super("Game of life");
    this.size = size;
    this.generations = generations;
    this.random = random;
    this.grid = grid;
    this.life = life;
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(300, 300);
    var contentPane = getContentPane();
    contentPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(contentPane, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    JLabel generationMaker = new JLabel("Generation: ");
    add(generationMaker);
    JLabel alive = new JLabel("Alive: 0");
    add(alive);

    var gridPanel = new JPanel();
    gridPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(size, size, 0, 0));
    contentPane.add(gridPanel);
    var cellArray = new javax.swing.JPanel[size][size];
    for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            var cell = new JPanel();
            cellArray[i][j] = cell;
            cell.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
            gridPanel.add(cell);
        }
    }
    contentPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(contentPane, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    var button = new JButton();
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            generateGrid(cellArray);
            alive.setText("Alive: " + countAlive(life.grid));
            incrementGeneration();
            generationMaker.setText("Generation #" + generationCounter);
        }
    });
    contentPane.add(button);
    setVisible(true);
}

private void generateGrid(JPanel[][] cellArray) {
    var grid2 = getGrid();
    fillInPanels(cellArray, grid2);
    life.grid = grid2;
}

protected void fillInPanels(javax.swing.JPanel[][] panelArray, boolean[][] grid) {
    for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            if (grid[i][j]) {
                panelArray[i][j].setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            } else {
                panelArray[i][j].setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It works fine, and is a great emulator of Conway's game of life, but it has a strange effect where the entire screen doesn't change right away, but you can see the individual cells changing, and not changing right away, right when I press the button. Is this because of double buffering? It works better when there are less cells alive on screen, and that is when it actually starts going quickly.

[Here is how it is like on a 35 by 35 size grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1IyrK.gif)

What is the source of the problem and how do I solve it? Please forgive me if I have poor formatting on either the question or the post, this is my first time posting here.

Comment: For better help sooner post a proper [mre] that demonstrates your issue. Probably you're doing some custom painting and have something in the `paintComponent` pausing your program. However [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42936135/2180785)'s an example of a GoL MRE that I did a few time ago. You can compare it with your current program or post the MRE requested so we can test it and see what's wrong

Comment: I did some more editing on my program and turns out the problem was that every time I changed a cell, in this case black to white or vice versa, the entire board was redrawn. I just put `setVisible` to  false when `fillInPanels` was active, and back to true when it was finished. I assume now I should answer my own question, correct?

Comment: You can do that or delete the question altogether, it's up to you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of the problem was that the grid was being redrawn every time I changed the paint color of a tile, from black to white or vice versa. Setting `setVisible` to false while `fillInPanels` was executing, and setting it back to true afterwards solved the issue.