# Conway's Game of Life's rules dont apply properly

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, conways-game-of-life

I'm currently starting to learn java and have tried recreating Conway's Game of Life. My code is kind of working as cells die and get born, but they dont seem to be following the intended rules. I'm using the following 2 methods for applying the rules:

```
public boolean nextState( int row, int col )
{
    if(a[row][col]==false)                                          //dead cells
    {
        int neighbors=0;
        for(int r=row-1; r<=row+1; r++)
        {
            for(int c=col-1; c<=col+1; c++)
            {
                if(r>=0 && c>=0 && r<a.length && c<a[0].length)        //exclude edges
                {
                    if(a[r][c])
                    {
                       neighbors++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if(neighbors==3)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else 
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    else                                                            //alive cells
    {
        int neighbors=-1;
        for(int r=row-1; r<=row+1; r++)
        {
            for(int c=col-1; c<=col+1; c++)
            {
                if(r>=0 && c>=0 && r<a.length && c<a[0].length)    //exclude edges
                {
                    if(a[r][c])
                    {
                        neighbors++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if(neighbors==3 || neighbors==2)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else 
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

public void nextGeneration()
{
    for(int r=0; r<a.length; r++)
    {
        for(int c=0; c<a[0].length; c++)
        {
            a[r][c]=nextState(r,c);
        }
    }
}
```

nextState returns whether the cell a[row][col] is dead or alive in the next Generation, depending on it's current status and it's amount of alive neighbors.

nextGeneration applies nextState to all the cells.

I'm struggling to realize why the status of certain cells does change but not in the intended way.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Just a hint, think about where you're storing the result of `nextState(r, c)`, and how that impacts the *next* call to `nextState(r, c)`.

Answer (score 4):

In Conway's Game of Life the cells must *not* be updated in-place. Instead, your function `nextGeneration` should use the values of the current grid and write the result into a different grid.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8200046/418556) for a working example that uses a separate array for the next generation.

Comment: thanks a lot, i found my mistakes. Really makes sense now.