# How i can draw a cellular automaton

Tags: java, swing, cellular-automata

I am doing an cellular automaton exercise in java and I came across a problem.

The logical part of the CA is working fine, if I wanted it to be arranged on the console it would be ready, but I want it to be drawn on the panel, when it is 1 drawing a black square, when it is 0 drawing a white square

Let's go to the problem

What is happening is that the whole logic runs normally, but when drawing java only draws the latest generation of CA, I read that java paintComponent only works when java decides to and not when it is called.

> My question is: how the best way to solve this problem and how to do it.

I thought of some things, but as I don't know java so well I decided to ask you

I thought about maybe saving all Arrays into one and then drawing from it (but I don't know how I could do it) I thought maybe there was a method of drawing in each loop, but I didn't find it (I used repaint () but it was no use)

Anyway, I would be grateful if someone gave me a solution, I have this problem for days and I have not found a solution, below is all the code

```java
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;    
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class CA extends JFrame {

    Rules rules = new Rules();

    public CA() {
        super("Cellular Automaton");
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(new GUI_CA(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
        setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                new CA();
            }   
        }); 
      }
    }
}
```

```java
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.Arrays;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JPanel;    

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class GUI_CA extends JPanel {

    int cellSize = 10;

    Rules rules = new Rules();

    private BufferedImage img;
    private Graphics2D g2d;

    public GUI_CA() {

        img =  new BufferedImage(cellSize, cellSize, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        g2d = (Graphics2D) img.createGraphics();

        evolution();    
    }

    public void evolution() {
        rules.cells = new int[987/cellSize];
        rules.cells[rules.cells.length/2] = 1;
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(rules.cells));
        for (int generationCount = 0; generationCount < 10; generationCount++) {
            rules.generate();
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(rules.cells));
            repaint();
        }           
    }

    public void drawCA(Graphics g) {

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        for (int i = 1; i < rules.cells.length -1; i++) {

            if (rules.cells[i] == 1) {
                g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                g2d.fillRect(i * cellSize, rules.generation * 5, cellSize, cellSize);
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(rules.cells));
            }else {
                g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                g2d.fillRect(i * cellSize, rules.generation * 5, cellSize, cellSize);
            }
        }


    }

    public void drawBackground(Graphics g) {

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        int width = 987;
        int height = 545;

        g2d.setPaint(Color.WHITE);
        g2d.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        drawBackground(g);
        drawCA(g);
        g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);

    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(987, 545);
    }

}
```

```java
public class Rules {

    int[] cells;
    int[] ruleSet = new int[] {0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0};
    //int cellSize = 10;
    int generation = 0;


    void generate() {

        int[] nextGeneration = new int[cells.length];

        for (int i = 1; i < cells.length - 1; i++) {

            int left = cells[i - 1];
            int me = cells[i];
            int right = cells [i + 1];

            nextGeneration[i] = rules(left, me, right);
        }
        cells = nextGeneration;
        generation++;

    }

    int rules(int left, int me, int right) {
        String s = "" + left + me + right;
        int index = Integer.parseInt(s, 2);
        //System.out.println(index);
        return ruleSet[index];      
    }
}
```

Comment: `Rules` seems to represent the current state of CA, right? Also it seems to be correct for me that it draws only the latest gen. What do you want to draw if not the current state?

Comment: What do you want your code to do differently?

Comment: See also this version of [game of life](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8200046/418556) for tips.

Comment: Thanks Andrew Thompson, I'll check it out

Comment: Tip: Add @Code-Apprentice (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GUI programming is different than console programming because you have to use the event system instead of just a while loop to repeat a task that generates output. I suggest that you start by adding a button that the user clicks to advance to the next generation of the automaton. When you get that working, you can take it a step further to add a timer that automatically goes to the next generation after a certain amount of time.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, that's helps a lots. I definitely will do this, thanks. Is there a way to the program do all de logic and then draw all the generations in one piece?

Comment: @AndreDilay What do you mean "draw all the generations in one piece"? What do you want the user to see on the screen?

Comment: i want to draw all the generations, the user will see the final pattern

Comment: Final pattern in case of CA usually means final generation, not all generations at once. Because what do you do for a final pattern if half the time a cell was white and the other half it was black? Draw it in grey? Or have a fully black/white screen?

Comment: I want to do something like this [rule 30] (https://www.google.com/search?q=rule+30+wolfram&safe=active&sxsrf=ACYBGNRmlQ6IqMTpPhLxJ3AnVTW0c0mWbg:1570623468672&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiD9bOvlI_lAhU5IrkGHZpUAbIQ_AUIEigB&biw=1366&bih=625#imgrc=_) and is that the user will see

Comment: @AndreDilay Interesting. I am only familiar with 2D CAs. With a 1D CA, you can generate each row with a for loop. I would start with a fixed number, like 10 generations for example.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice thanks for the help, it's been very useful, but that's the problem, what i was trying to do is check all the cells of generation, than print it a than restart the process in the next generation, in the end result will be like the image, in this moment im studing the button method that you said, and i think that could do it right. From the time that i met CA i was facinated, and i think i will learn a lot with it, i making a final paper, i hope that i can explain well. thanks a lot for your help

Comment: @AndreDilay What I have in mind is something like this: create a new method named something like `drawAllGenerations()`. This has a loop that calls `rules.generate()` and then `drawCA()`. Now you call this `drawAllGenerations()` directly from `paintComponent()` instead of calling `drawCA()`. You will also need to modify `drawCA()` to adjust the y-coordinate of the cells that it draws.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice That´s works, thanks a lot, i'll need do some adjustments to work properly, wow thanks a lot

Comment: @Code-Apprentice works as intended [Results Rule 30] (https://imgur.com/7w16eK5) thanks a lot

Comment: @AndreDilay Glad you got it to work. Note how I broke the problem down and described a solution in (mostly) English. This is often the first critical step in writing a computer program. Usually I write my steps as a bulleted or numbered list rather than in paragraph form. (For future notice, there shouldn't be a space between the `]` and the `(` to make a link in your comment.)

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Thanks for the tips, i'll take note of these