# Reset Game Of Life Gui

Tags: java, swing

I am making Conway's Game of Life using Java Swing. I am using a 2D arrays of buttons to paint the cells. The problem I have right now is that I implemented a button which will clear the pattern or patterns drew manually o randomly and also while the timer is running. I want to clear or restart the 2D array of buttons but when I try to draw it doesn't work.

> Here I have the Action Listeners for each button

//Starts the timer

```
    Starter.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            timer.start();
            cells = new JButton[size][size];
        }

    });
    //Stops the timer
    Stop.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            timer.stop();
        }

    });
    //Clears de buttons which are painted
    clear.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
                for(int j = 0; j < size; j++){
                    if(Univers[i][j]){
                        cells[i][j].setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                    }
                }
            }
            Arrays.fill(cells, null);
        }
    });
```

> All the code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.*;

public class GameOfLife extends JFrame{
    int size=15;
    int time=0;
    boolean Univers[][];
    JButton cells[][];
    //int countentry=0;
    //List<boolean[][]> Record;
    JComboBox combobox;
    public GameOfLife() {
        //Record = new ArrayList<>();
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 600));
        pack();
        setLayout(null);
        /*combobox= new JComboBox();
        combobox.addItem("Records");
        combobox.addItem(time+"s");
        */
        Random rnd=new Random();
        Univers=new boolean[size][size];
        cells=new JButton[size][size];
        JPanel UniversPanel=new JPanel();
        UniversPanel.setBounds(0,0,500,500);
        UniversPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(size,size));
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //manual cell adding
        MouseListener mouseListener = new MouseListener(){
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) { }
            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) { }
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) { }
            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) { }
            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                JButton ch = (JButton) e.getSource();
                //System.out.println(ch.getLocation(getLocation()));
                int sizegrid = UniversPanel.getSize(getSize()).width / size;
                int i = (ch.getLocation(getLocation()).x) / sizegrid;
                int z = (ch.getLocation(getLocation()).y) / sizegrid;
                //System.out.println("x= "+i);
                //System.out.println("y= "+z);

                if (!Univers[z][i] && SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(e)) {
                    Univers[z][i] = true;
                    cells[z][i].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
                }
                if(Univers[z][i] && SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton(e)) {
                    Univers[z][i]=false;
                    cells[z][i].setBackground(Color.BLACK);

                }
            }

        };
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        for(int x=0;x<size;x++) {
            for(int y=0;y<size;y++) {
                /*if((x==0 && y==1 )|| (x==1 && y==1) || (x==2 && y==1)) {
                    Univers[x][y]=true;
                }else {
                    Univers[x][y]=false;
                }*/
                Univers[x][y]=false;
                //Univers[x][y]=rnd.nextInt(100)<20;
                JButton btn=new JButton();
                if(Univers[x][y]) {
                    btn.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
                }else {
                    btn.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                }
                UniversPanel.add(btn);
                cells[x][y]=btn;


            }


        }
        //Record.add(Univers);
        //countentry+=1;
        //System.out.print(Record.size());
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        int delay=100;//milliseconds
        //int Timeup=5000/delay;
        Timer timer=new Timer(delay,new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                boolean[][] tempUnivers=new boolean[size][size];
                //countentry+=1;
                for(int x=0;x<size;x++) {
                    for(int y=0;y<size;y++) {
                        int count=Neigbours(x,y);
                        if(Univers[x][y]) {
                            if(count<2) {
                                tempUnivers[x][y]=false;
                            }
                            if(count==3 ||count==2) {
                                tempUnivers[x][y]=true;
                            }
                            if(count>3) {
                                tempUnivers[x][y]=false;
                            }
                        }else{
                            if(count==3)
                                tempUnivers[x][y]=true;

                        }

                    }
                }
                Univers=tempUnivers;
                //Record.add(Univers);
                //System.out.print(Record.size());
                for(int x=0;x<size;x++) {
                    for(int y=0;y<size;y++) {
                        if(Univers[x][y]) {
                            cells[x][y].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
                        }else {
                            cells[x][y].setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                        }

                    }

                }
        /*  if(countentry==Timeup) {
                time+=5;
                combobox.addItem(time+"s");
                countentry=0;
            }
        */
            }
        });

        for(int x=0;x<size;x++) {
            for(int y=0;y<size;y++) {
                cells[x][y].addMouseListener(mouseListener);
            }
        }


        //Slider
        /*JPanel PanelSlider =new JPanel();
        PanelSlider.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,2));
        PanelSlider.setBounds(0,510,300,50);
        JSlider slider = new JSlider(0,5,0);
        slider.setPaintTrack(true);
        slider.setPaintTicks(true);
        slider.setPaintLabels(true);
        slider.setMajorTickSpacing(1);
        slider.setMinorTickSpacing(1/10);
        slider.setBounds(51, 88, 277, 52);
        PanelSlider.add(combobox);
        PanelSlider.add(slider);
        */
        //Buttons
        JPanel PanelButton =new JPanel();
        PanelButton.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,3));
        PanelButton.setBounds(0,510,200,50);
        JButton Starter=new JButton("Start");
        PanelButton.add(Starter);
        JButton Stop=new JButton("Stop");
        PanelButton.add(Stop);
        JButton clear = new JButton("Clear");
        PanelButton.add(clear);

        //Starts the timer
        Starter.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                timer.start();
                cells = new JButton[size][size];
            }

        });
        //Stops the timer
        Stop.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                timer.stop();
            }

        });
        //Clears de buttons which are painted
        clear.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
                    for(int j = 0; j < size; j++){
                        if(Univers[i][j]){
                            cells[i][j].setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                        }
                    }
                }
                Arrays.fill(cells, null);
            }
        });



        //add(PanelSlider);

        add(UniversPanel);
        add(PanelButton);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);


    }
    int Neigbours(int i, int z) {
        int count=0;
        for(int x=i-1;x<=i+1;x++) {
            for(int y=z-1;y<=z+1;y++) {
                try {
                    if(Univers[x][y]) {
                        count++;
                    }
                }catch(Exception e){
                    //System.out.println(e);
                }
            }
        }
        if(Univers[i][z])
            count--;

        return count;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new GameOfLife();

    }
    //Slider info https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/slider.html
    //Manual insert void ActionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){add jbutton ch = (Jbutton) ae.getSource();}
}
```

Comment: It's much easier to use a drawing JPanel and paint the grid and cells.  The Oracle tutorial, [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) will show you how.  Here's [one way](https://github.com/ggleblanc2/conways-life) to create the game.

Comment: Perhaps it has the same problem as was addressed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8199460/issue-with-game-of-life/8200046#8200046).

Comment: Other tips: 1) `setLayout(null);` Elsewhere the code seems to use layouts. Do so consistently. 2) `setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 600));` That is the wrong size. It makes sense to have the 'world' a particular size, but the frame containing it needs to be bigger to account for the frame decorations. The correct size is given by calling.. 3) `pack();` after all components are added.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Actually I have some problems with the layout containing the buttons and another layout containing those three buttons but when I try to resize the window these layouts stay static and I want to fix that, I am pretty new at Java swing so getting around some things is actually a pain in the ass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read the comment within the code to follow the changes made in the code and the recommendations:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.MouseInputAdapter;

    public class GameOfLife extends JFrame{

    //declare constants
    private final int BOARD_SIZE=15,
            ANIMATION_DELAY=100;//milliseconds;
    private final Cell cells[][];

    public GameOfLife() {

        //setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 600)); let layout manager work out the size derived from children
        //setLayout(null);   avoid using null layouts and seting bounds manually

        cells=new Cell[BOARD_SIZE][BOARD_SIZE];
        JPanel universPanel=new JPanel();
        //universPanel.setBounds(0,0,500,500); let the layout manager set bounds
        universPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(BOARD_SIZE,BOARD_SIZE));

        //initialize all cells
        for(int x=0;x<BOARD_SIZE;x++) {
            for(int y=0;y<BOARD_SIZE;y++) {
                Cell cell=new Cell();
                universPanel.add(cell);
                cells[x][y]=cell;
            }
        }

        //move the animation code to a method for better readability
        Timer timer=new Timer(ANIMATION_DELAY,e -> animate());

        //Buttons
        JPanel panelButton =new JPanel();
        panelButton.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,3));
        //panelButton.setBounds(0,510,200,50); let the layout manager set bounds
        JButton starter=new JButton("Start");
        panelButton.add(starter);
        JButton stop=new JButton("Stop");
        panelButton.add(stop);
        JButton clear = new JButton("Clear");
        panelButton.add(clear);

        //Starts the timer
        starter.addActionListener(e ->  timer.start());

        //Stops the timer
        stop.addActionListener(e -> timer.stop());

        //Resets all cells
        clear.addActionListener(e -> {
            for(int i = 0; i < BOARD_SIZE; i++){
                for(int j = 0; j < BOARD_SIZE; j++){
                    cells[i][j].setUniverse(false);
                }
            }
            //Arrays.fill(cells, null); no need to set to null.
        });

        //add(PanelSlider);
        //add to appropriate BorderLayout positions
        add(universPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(panelButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack(); //pack after you added all components
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private void animate(){
        for(int x1=0;x1<BOARD_SIZE;x1++) {
            for(int y1=0;y1<BOARD_SIZE;y1++) {
                int count=numberOfNeigboursAround(x1,y1);
                if(cells[x1][y1].isUniverse()) {
                    if(count<2) {
                        cells[x1][y1].setUniverse(false);
                    }else if//process next if only if previous one was false
                          (count==3 ||count==2) {
                        cells[x1][y1].setUniverse(true);
                    }else if(count>3) {
                        cells[x1][y1].setUniverse(false);
                    }
                }else if(count==3) {
                        cells[x1][y1].setUniverse(true);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private int numberOfNeigboursAround(int x, int y) {
        int count=0;
        for(int xIndex=x-1;xIndex<=x+1;xIndex++) {
            for(int yIndex=y-1;yIndex<=y+1;yIndex++) {
                //make sure index is valid
                if(xIndex >= BOARD_SIZE || xIndex < 0 || yIndex >= BOARD_SIZE || yIndex < 0) {
                    continue;
                }

                //don't process center cell
                if(xIndex == x&&yIndex ==y) {
                    continue;
                }
                if(cells[xIndex][yIndex].isUniverse()) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }

        return count;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new GameOfLife();
    }
}

//Introduce a Cell class with the needed properties. Since button functionality i snot
//use a JLabel can be used to represent a cell
class Cell extends JLabel{

    private static Color BOARD = Color.BLACK, UNIVERSE = Color.GREEN, BORDER = Color.GRAY;
    private static Dimension CELL_SIZE = new Dimension(30,30);
    private boolean universe;

    public Cell() {
        super();
        universe = false;
        setOpaque(true);
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(BORDER, 2));
        setBackground(BOARD);
        //add mouse listener. use MouseInputAdapter to implement only needed methods
        addMouseListener( new MouseInputAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                mouseClicksHandler(e);
            }
        });
    }

    public boolean isUniverse() {
        return universe;
    }

    public void setUniverse(boolean isUniverse) {
        if (universe == isUniverse) return;  //no change
        universe = isUniverse;
        setBackground(isUniverse ? UNIVERSE : BOARD);
        repaint();
    }

    private void mouseClicksHandler(MouseEvent e){
        if (SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(e)) {
            setUniverse(true);
        }else  //if first if is true no need to evaluate the second if
            if( SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton(e)) {
                setUniverse(false);
            }
    }

    //preferred size used by layout managers
    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return CELL_SIZE;
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't notice one issue with your version, it create more cells than it should be. For instance, if you paint three cells in a vertical line it should rotate in an endless loop.

Comment: Are you referring to the logic of setting a cell to setting cells to true or false in animate() ?

Comment: I think the logic inside that method it's fine but it is not not being applied correctly. As I said before, it creates more cells than it should, also some rules are not being applied.

Comment: My answer, in line with the question, is about Swing animation and resting it.  Did it answer the question? I did not investigate the cell-creation logic.

Comment: Okay, I just addressed that problem in case other users use your answer as an example. Yes you did answer my question about Swing, thank you.